# gradient of tensor multiplied by vector, Laplacian of tensor multiplied by vector

Tags: calculus, tensors

What identies can be applied to multiply out the terms in

$\nabla\left( T\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)$

and

$\nabla^{2}\left( T\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)$

where $T$ is a tensor and $\mathbf{v}$ a vector?

Thanks!

Comment: so I'm going to end up with a third rank tensor like $\nabla T$ at some point aren't I?

Comment: Yes that's more than likely

Answer (score 0):

Assume $T$ is a second-rank tensor. We can proceed componentwise in an arbitrary Cartesian orthonormal system. By using Einstein notation, definitions and the product rule give
\begin{aligned}
\left[\nabla(T\cdot {\bf v})\right]_{ij} = (T_{ik}v_k)_{,j} = v_k T_{ik,j} + T_{ik}v_{k,j} = ({\bf v}^\top\!\cdot\nabla T^\top + T\cdot\nabla {\bf v})_{ij} \, .
\end{aligned}
One can proceed similarly for the other formula.

Comment: OK, thanks, I was able to perform that calculation. So $\nabla T$ is a third order tensor. What's the definition of a divergence of such a tensor?

Comment: @phryas $\text{div}∇T=∇(∇T):I$ where $I$ is the second order identity tensor and $:$ is double contraction